# NTFS signature is missing

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++, ntfs, ntfs-3g

I have loaded **NTFS-3G** from here: https://github.com/vitalif/ntfs-3g into a VS2017 project, wanting to read *NTFS USB stick drive*. And when I debugging reading process, I saw that is not reading USB drive due to:

```
// bootsect.c

BOOL ntfs_boot_sector_is_ntfs(NTFS_BOOT_SECTOR* b)
{
    u32 i;
    BOOL ret = FALSE;
    ntfs_log_debug("Beginning bootsector check.\n");

    ntfs_log_debug("Checking OEMid, NTFS signature.\n");
    if (b->oem_id != const_cpu_to_le64(0x202020205346544eULL))  // "NTFS    "
    {
        ntfs_log_error("NTFS signature is missing.\n");        // <-- my code is running here ...
        goto not_ntfs;
    }
...
...
```

I run it this code on Win10 64bit/VS2017. And my USB stick are valid, I have tried several USB stick (all of them NTFS).

I read that vitalif/ntfs-3g has a OS limitation: Windows XP, ... and Windows 7 file systems ... that is why I suspect the cause of my failing reading process ...

I have seek it on github for another NTFS-3G project that support Win10, I didn't found it ... is there anywhere another version of NTFS-3G library that work on Win10 ? Or, could another cause for my failing ?

Any support will be wellcome, I am struggle for this issue for days and days ...

Comment: [perhaps here?](https://www.tuxera.com/community/open-source-ntfs-3g/)  _It provides safe handling of the Windows XP, Windows Server 2003, Windows 2000, Windows Vista, Windows Server 2008, Windows 7, Windows 8_ ***and Windows 10 NTFS file systems.***

Comment: But I read inside that archive that is supporting until Win7 too ..

Comment: Why are you using NTFS-3G?  From the first sentence : "NTFS-3G is a stable, full-featured, read-write NTFS driver for Linux, Android, Mac OS X, FreeBSD, NetBSD, OpenSolaris, QNX, Haiku, and other operating systems." -- it provides NTFS support on those OS that do not natively support NTFS.  Windows 10 natively supports NTFS ... if you are having issues reading your Thumb-drive on a Windows 10 box, you have other issues that NTFS-3G will not help with.

Comment: How are you reading the data from the drive? What do you get instead of the correct signature?